# RAID 5 array degraded - Intel Matrix Storage Manager suddenly says all 4 disks are "Non-raid disks"

Tags: power, raid-5

Long story short, I have a linux (ubuntu 10.04 LTS) server with a 4 disks configured as a 2 TB RAID 5, set up with Intel Matrix Storage Manager v8.0.0.1038 in BIOS. My power went out, and the UPS power backup couldn't keep the server going long enough until the power came back on. The RAID degraded, and now I can't boot the server.

When the power finally came back on, I rebooted and was dumped directly to a GRUB command line. When I rebooted again with command-I to see what Intel Matrix Storage Manager could tell me about the RAID array, it claimed there *was* no RAID array, just these 4 disks:

```
RAID Volumes: 
None defined 

Port  Drive Model     Serial #        Size    Type/Status(Vol ID)
0      SAMSUNG  [snip]                        Non-RAID Disk
1      SAMSUNG  [snip]                        Non-RAID Disk
2      SAMSUNG  [snip]                        Non-RAID Disk
3      SAMSUNG  [snip]                        Non-RAID Disk
```

What? How did they become Non-RAID Disks just from a power outage? Further, I now only see these menu items in Intel Matrix Storage Manager:

```
1) Create RAID volume
2) Delete RAID volume
3) Reset disks to Non-RAID
4) Exit
```

How do I convince Intel Matrix Storage Manager to treat these 4 disks as a RAID array again? Have I lost all these data (yes I have a backup, but it's a few weeks old). Do I have to remake the RAID array and rebuild all the data on the drives?

Comment: A detail that may or may not be related - from reading the IMSM manual, it seems that IMSM doesn't support booting from RAID array's greater than 2 TB in size. I originally made this array as a smaller 3 disk array and then expanded it. It could be that IMSM decided after the power cut to check the size of the array and then retroactively make it non-bootable. Just a guess at this point though.